# What is the difference between "go for" and "go with" in the sense of choosing something?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between *go for* and *go with* in the sense of choosing something? For example:

> I was offered a few jobs and I will probably  **go for** the one with higher pay.
>
> I was offered a few jobs and I will probably **go with** the one with higher pay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of "go for" and "go with" in that context is the same.
 To me, the phrase "go for" has a connotation of seizing or grabbing something, while "go with" has a connotation of accompanying or going along with something, but in that context, it amounts to the same thing.